Efficient Approach to Decompressed String Substring Problem
The problem involves decompressing a compressed string and outputting the substring in the range of L and R. For example:

A(BB(CC)) -> ABBCCCCBBCCCC


L = 52, R = 60,
((((((((IMTOOSTRONG)))))))) -> IMTOOSTRONGIMTOOSTRONGIMTOOSTRONG...


MTOOSTRON

Here, the characters inside the parentheses are repeated, and the goal is to decompress the string and then output the substring in the given range [L, R].
The challenge is that the range [L, R] can go up to 1 billion, so decompressing the entire string would result in TLE (Time Limit Exceeded). I can’t figure out how to approach this problem efficiently.
How can I efficiently extract a substring from a nested compressed string without fully decompressing it, given that the range [L, R] can be as large as 1 billion?
I attempted to think about strategies like:
Using recursion or a stack-based approach to simulate decompression.
Counting the length of the decompressed string without fully expanding it, to decide which parts of the string are relevant for the [L, R] range.

(I think one of your approaches promising.)

Thank you for your feedback! I'm glad to hear that one of my approaches seems promising.
However, I'm struggling to figure out which specific data structures or implementation techniques would be most suitable to make this approach efficient.
Could you provide some hints or point me in the right direction?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Put efficient to the back of your mind. What is the simplest thing that could possibly work acceptably? How can you check it works as specified? Check automatically, at that? What are its resource requirements? R being large is no problem when L is small: the output would be large. What about large L?

Thank you for the feedback but, I’ve already implemented a solution that fully decompresses the string and retrieves the desired substring. While it works for small inputs, it’s obviously inefficient for large values of [L, R], especially when the range can go up to 1 billion.
The main challenge I’m facing is figuring out how to handle large numbers without fully decompressing the string. I suspect the solution involves keeping track of segment lengths dynamically during parsing, but I’m unsure how to efficiently determine which parts of the string are relevant to the range [L, R].

"already implemented a [brute force] solution" fine. Once you have plausibly implemented automatic testing of solutions, excellent! Then (and only then) move on to decompressing just what you need for output.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Which programming language are you using?

Your example lacks values of L and R and the resulting output

"the range [L, R] can go up to 1 billion" hmm... You want to output 1 billion characters? And then you think it matters how long time the decompression time takes! No, no, no... Makes no sense!! If the range [L,R] is 5 and the decompressed string is a billion characters then it may make sense to only decompress a part but if you want to print a huge number then the decompress is nothing. I think you got it wrong

Too bad the asker has not reacted anymore. :-(

Sorry for the late reply :(
I posted more speicifed output sample.
And I'm using C++ mainly.
I'm very thankful to all of you guys sharing your ideas with this question

I don't get "the strong example" - 1) does the string start at 1 or at 0? 2) R seems to be interpreted to be inclusive - are the numbers represented in regular decimal?

For the "strong example", I would expect the result to be "ONGIMTOOS", not "MTOOSTRON". The repeated string "IMTOOSTRONG" has 11 characters, so it repeats at indices 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, ... At index 52, we are three characters before the next repetition, so the resulting substring should start with "ONG". I don't understand why you say it should be "MTOOSTRON". Please clarify.

I would suggest building a tree where the root represents the whole string, and every child represents either a substring represented by parentheses, or a literal string (without parentheses). The leaves of this tree are the literal strings.
Each node would also store the size of the (sub)string it represents (when decompressed).
To represent the repetition factor, you could add another node property that is either 1 or 2. Or, alternatively, you could define the same child node (reference) as a duplicated child of its parent: this creates two edges between the same node pair, so giving that relation a cardinality of 2. Note that this latter approach would turn the tree into a polytree.
Finally define a substring method on nodes which can then use recursion to retrieve the string representations that are relevant for the given range.
Here is an implementation in a JavaScript snippet:


class Node {
    constructor() {
        this.length = 0; // Length of represented string (in uncompressed form)
        this.children = []; // List of strings and child nodes
    }
    addChild(child) { // child could be a Node or a string
        this.length += child.length;
        this.children.push(child);
    }
    substring(start, stop) { // `stop` is excluded from the range
        if (start >= this.length || stop <= 0 || start >= stop) return "";
        let size = stop - start;
        return this.children.map(child => {
            // If child is a string, the native substring method is called here,
            //    otherwise it is a recursive call:
            const s = child.substring(start, start + size);
            start -= child.length;
            return s;
        }).join("");
    }
}

function getTokenIterator(compressed) {
    // Return an iterator over the substrings that either 
    //    are "(", ")" or a series of other characters
    return compressed.match(/[^()]+|./gs).values();
}

function createGraph(tokens) {
    const node = new Node;
    while (true) {
        const token = tokens.next().value;
        if (!token || token === ")") return node;
        if (token === "(") {
            const child = createGraph(tokens);
            // Add child twice to reflect repetition
            node.addChild(child);
            node.addChild(child);
        } else {
            node.addChild(token);
        }
    }
}

function getSlice(compressed, left, right) {
    const tokens = getTokenIterator(compressed);
    const root = createGraph(tokens);
    // As `right` is inclusive in the range, add 1:
    return root.substring(left, right+1);
}

// Example runs
console.log(getSlice("AA(BB(CC))", 3, 8)); // BCCCCB
console.log(getSlice("((((((((IMTOOSTRONG))))))))", 52, 60));



Complexity analysis
Let  be the length of the input string.
The algorithm has these parts:

Tokenizing: the input string is scanned from left to right, which is O(), creating the token strings, which also totals to O().

Tree building: For each token the processing has O(1) time complexity. This consist of either making a recursive call and attaching a node twice to the graph, or making a leaf node. So this totals to O().

Getting the substring: this involves traversing the polytree. Here the worst case complexity has two components:

It is determined by the size of the output string (i.e. −+1 assuming these are valid indices in the uncompressed string). In the worst case an input string consists of a deeply nested string (like your "strong example"), and if =0 and  is maximised, the whole compressed string might need to be expanded. Take for example  as odd, and the first /2 characters are opening parentheses, the middle character is "A", and the remaining /2 characters are closing parentheses. Then the uncompressed string has 2/2 characters. As producing a string needs O(1) per character, the time complexity is O(2) for this scenario. If we include  and  in this expression, it becomes O(min(2, −)).

When −+1 is small, like 1, the complexity is not just O(1). There is the overhead of the polytree traversal. The traversal needs to find a leaf (for ), which in the worst case may involve visiting all internal nodes twice (because they are repeated), where each time a node's children are visited (only) upon the node's second visit. At some point we reach the leaf that is determined by  and unwind out of recursion again. The work to go from  and  (while producing output) was discussed in the previous paragraph, so I omit it here.


This means that the number of distinct nodes is a determining factor also, which is O().


Taking all this together the overall complexity can be expressed as:
O(min(2, −) + )

Thank you for your opionion!
What do you expect the time complexity to be?
Then, the tree would be binary tree?

I added a section to my answer with complexity analysis. No, the graph is not a tree (like I explained in my answer), but a polytree. It is not binary: a node can have more than two children. For instance, for input "A(B)C(D)E(F)", the root node has 9 edges to leaf nodes (some of which are duplicate node references, as there are only 6 distinct leaf nodes), each representing one letter.
